# Recovery Group with Exchange 2003 and Python

Tags: python, vbscript, exchange-server

Is there a way to create a recovery group in exchange 2003 with python?

Maybe CDOEXM or VBScript? But I have been unsuccessful in finding any sample code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to just install powershell on the machine and use that.